# Changing the type of action parameter at runtime depending on current user in aspnet webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model, model-binding, action-filter

How to alter the `TViewModel` from within a `action filter` or a `model binder`?

```
   [HasPriviliege]
   public IHttpActionResult Get(long id)
    {
        var entity = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TViewModel, TEntity>(model);
        repo.Update(id, entity);
        repo.Save();
        return Ok(model);
    }

   [HasPriviliege]
   public IHttpActionResult Edit(long id, TViewModel model)
    {
        var entity = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TViewModel, TEntity>(model);
        repo.Update(id, entity);
        repo.Save();
        return Ok(model);
    }
```

the filter should be

```
public class HasPriviliege:ActionFilterAttribute
{ 
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    { 
        if(getPrivileges()=="doctor"){
           //the TViewModel(view model type to bind to) should be
           // DoctorPatientViewModel should be;
        }else{
           //the TViewModel(view model type to bind to) should be 
            //ExaminationPatientViewModel
     }
        //base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

or alternativaly, the model binder

```
 public class IPrivilegeableModelBinder: IModelBinder
{
      public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                          ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
      { 
    //return (hasPriviliege()?DoctorPatientViewModel:ExaminationPatientViewModel) ;
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure if this is going to help, but I've accomplished something like this but at the controller level.  We created a controller factory that was able to inspect the request and new up a generic `Controller<T>`.  The actions then able to work with this.

Comment: Exactly but where do you set the type `T` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than write an over-bloated comment, I'll post my suggestion on how we accomplished something similar to this using a generic controller.

Controller factory:

```
public class ControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        Type controllerType = typeof(GenericController<>);
        Type genericType = controllerType.MakeGenericType(GetPrivilegeType());
        ConstructorInfo ctor = genericType.GetConstructor(new Type[]{});
        return (IController)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { });
    }

    public SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        ...
        return SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly;
    }

    public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        if (controller is IDisposable)
        {
            ((IDisposable)controller).Dispose();
        }
    }

    private string GetPrivilegeType()
    {
        if (getPrivileges() == "doctor") {
            return typeof(DoctorPatientViewModel);
        } else {
            return typeof(ExaminationPatientViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Register it like this:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new ControllerFactory());
```

...and finally what your controller might look like

```
public class GenericController<TViewModel> // TViewModel will be the privilege type from the factory
    where TViewModel : IPrivilege
{
    [HasPriviliege]
    public IHttpActionResult Edit(long id, TViewModel model)
    {
        var entity = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TViewModel, TEntity>(model);
        repo.Update(id, entity);
        repo.Save();
        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

That's the most basic example to get a generic controller working for mvc which might go some way to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you. this helped despite I have edited your code to let things work `...` 
`Type genericType = controllerType.MakeGenericType(new Type[]{});
            ConstructorInfo ctor = genericType.GetConstructor(new Type[]{});`

Comment: Ok, good.  It was a blind, cut/chop effort to only get the necessary parts - I've updated now.

Comment: Do you figure out how this can be accomplished using WebApi?

Comment: I guess, you'll likely need to register a `IHttpControllerSelector` (out of the box, the framework uses [DefaultHttpControllerSelector](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/6248bfd24c31356e75a31c1b1030d4d96f669a6a/src/System.Web.Http/Dispatcher/DefaultHttpControllerSelector.cs)).  Then override `SelectController` which returns a `HttpControllerDescriptor`.  This type then has method `CreateController` returning `IController` which is likely to be the hook from WebApi to find the controller for the request.